# Dropdown tabs stay on active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

If you press on menu item than go to another one it's not possible to go back to the one you came from, because all stay on active.

How can I fix this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are possible using bootstrap's built in events. Put the following in your html just before the close body tag. This effectively removes all `active` classes from li's when the menu is shown.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(){
            $(".dropdown-menu li").removeClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53yx4mfz/1/)

[Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns-methods)